# Phase neutral earth fault indicator circuit

Tags: grounding, mains

I came across the following circuit on a random website:

[image: phase neutral earth fault detection circuit]

[Source website](https://theorycircuit.com/phase-neutral-earth-fault-indicator-circuit-diagram/)

My guess is this circuit is used by some extension boards as shown below:

[image: extension board]

I understand that LED1 current (around 2 mA) is flowing into the earth when things are working fine.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is this an acceptable practice in general?
2. Will it cause the RCCB/ELCB to trip, assuming someone is using 20-30 such products (extension boards)?

Comment: Actually, the current through the LEDs would be about 230/56 = 4.1 mA.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy - i am considering half pulse only assuming negative pulse won't pass. that's why I am getting half of what you got.

Comment: Yes, I should have taken that into account. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is this an acceptable practice in general?*

If you mean is the circuit suitable then the answer us a big fat "no". LEDs have a maximum reverse voltage that is at best tens of volts and not hundreds of volts.

> *Will it cause the RCCB/ELCB to trip, assuming someone is using 20-30
> such products*

The design is flawed; it will burn first so I'd be more inclined to worry about that than worrying about tripping an RCCB.